# El valor del textarea no cambia angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo este codigo el cual muestra un par de variables que son traidas a traves de una api en php, el problema es que no muestra nada en el textarea, es como si la variable estuviera vacia y no lo esta, le hago un console.log , funciona perfectamente con el input pero no con el textarea

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <br>
    <div class="form__group mx-auto">
        <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="Titulo" name="titulo" value="{{historia.titulo}}" required />
        <label for="name" class="form__label">Titulo</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea name="contenido" rows="15" cols="70"  class="form-control">{{historia.contenido}}</textarea>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo de typescript:

```
this.apiService.GetHistoria(this.id_historia).subscribe(
      e=>{
        this.historia=e;
        console.log(this.historia.contenido);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, te pido que pases el código con la declaración y model del Object historia.

Comment: Listo amigo y muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes probar si lo pasas así funciona? [value]="nuevaHistoria.contenido"

Comment: y te aconsejo que pongas en <div class="container text-center"> una bandera ngif para mostrar el contenido cuando cargue el observable y no tengas errores en consoles de variables undefined. *ngIf="historia"

Comment: Gracias bro me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione agregandolo en el atributo value:

```
<textarea name="contenido" rows="15" cols="70" [(ngModel)]="nuevahistoria.contenido" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;text-align: center;" placeholder="Escribe tu historia..." class="form-control" value="{{historia.contenido}}"></textarea>
```